# How can I get multiple Jenkins builds to work from one local git repo?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a GitHub repo that's big and contains several independently build-able bits. If I configure Jenkins with a job (or two) for each of these, I end up with having to pull gigabytes of data multiple times (one clone of the repo for each job).

This takes both diskspace and bandwidth.

What I'd like to do is have "Refresh local repo" job that clones github once, then configure each of the jobs to clone themselves from that repo, and build. Then by setting up the sub-jobs as dependent builds, I can run "Refresh local repo", have it pull all the latest stuff from GitHub, then have each of the builds run.

So far I've got the "Refresh local repo" working - it clones successfully, and if I go to the workspace, I see that it has the HEAD commit of origin/master.

The problem is the other jobs - these don't seem to be picking up updates. Here's how I've got one of them configured:

```
Git
 Repository URL file:////Users/malcolmbox/.jenkins/jobs/Refresh Local repo/workspace
 Branches to build  master
```

Instead of this updating to the latest commit, it's stuck several days in the past.

How can I get it to pull the tip and do the right thing?

To clarify: the .../Refresh Local repo/workspace has commit 6b20268389064590147d5c73d2b6aceb6ba5fe70 submitted 28/3

The dependent build, after running a build (so presumably doing a git clone/pull step) is checked out to 79a25992cc192376522bcb634ee0f7eb3033fc7e submitted 26/3 - so it's a couple of days behind.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you open the job configuration and click on the Advanced button of the git SCM configuration, you will see a place to specify "Path of the reference repo to use during clone (optional)".

If you have a local clone of your repository, add the path to the reference repo field.

Git will then use the local clone and share most of the git objects on the disk and pulling from github only what is missing from the local clone resulting in lightning fast clones and saved disk space.

Or is this exactly how you have configured your job and it is not picking up latest commits? If that is so, please provide more details. Consider publishing your job configuration.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify: It seems latest git plugin now has a popup menu of advanced options and the reference repo is under "Advanced clone behavior".

Comment: How does this path look like? Meaning, it is absolute file system path? Can I use other job name as root of path?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think an absolute path is needed. Job name does not have a meaning in the file system, especially on a slave.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Clone Workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin). You can either use that or configure a job to update a local repository from Github and then have all the other jobs pull from that local repo.

This won't help with the problem that the workspaces still need the diskspace, but as far as I know there's no simple solution for that. You could either have the build steps change to a shared directory outside the workspace, but that's hacky and might break other things. Alternatively, you could use a filesystem that provides deduplication.

Comment: I'm less worried about diskspace, and anyway I believe git is smart and uses links where possible when cloning a local repo. Getting all the other jobs to pull from the local repo is what I want to do - but I can't figure out how. It seems they don't pull new commits even through the local repo has them.

Comment: How do you trigger the builds? Have you tried polling the local repo and checking the poll log?

Comment: I use the "Build after" trigger on the secondary builds

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience.

I have one job to pull the real remote repo, which is github.

Each of the other jobs (there are many) has a "Repository URL" like this:

```
file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/webtest-local-repo/workspace/.git
```

It clones fine, but subsequent fetches don't notice any changes.

The same issue presents in gitbash, so i guess this is a git issue, not a jenkins issue.

My **horrific workaround** was to make the dependent jobs delete their workspaces when finished building, so that every git operation is a "clone."  It's ridiculous, but maybe less ridiculous than having a zillion jobs banging away at the same github repo.

**ZOMG!**  That didn't work either, because while git could successfully clone the repo, jenkins would remember the previous revision and build the very same one again.  Perhaps it's related to [this issue](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/how-to-build-a-specific-git-branch-with-jenkins-td4576864.html), i dunno, i'm pretty fed up.  We gave up, and now all the jobs poll github again.  Maybe i'll get a hook working instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a multi-configuration Jenkins job that just checks out your repo, and builds periodically. It doesn't have to build on every commit, since your other repos will automatically pull any changes from the actual remote if it doesn't find them in this repo.
2. Open the "label" section of the configuration matrix, and check off each build node individually.
3. On your other jobs, click on the Advanced button of the git SCM configuration, and find "Path of the reference repo to use during clone (optional)". Enter `$WORKSPACE/../ReferenceRepo/label/$NODE_NAME`, where `ReferenceRepo` is the name of the job you created above.

You will need to re-clone each of your jobs on each machine for this to take effect. They should now use the data from the reference repo for everything they can, saving you disk space and bandwidth on your build nodes.