# Jenkinsfile: git folder

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I have a problem I'm working with jenkinsfile, I'm working on a development branch, within that branch I have two folders, one API and one FRONT, I need some way when the commit is done and jenkins identifies which folder it belongs to and the api or from the front. in my application he is building both at the same time and doing the deployment, he needs it to build only if there is a change in one of them and does not stay every time building both, but researching I did not find any answer.

```
node{
    if (a == 0) {
         def status = sh (returnStdout:true, script:'cd /home/cadmus/GooBeeTeams_Git/goobeeteams/goobeeteams/goobeeteams.webapp && docker image build -t goobeeteams_frontend .')
                    if (status == 0) {
                        sh 'docker container rm -f goobeeteams_api_1'
                        // Success!
                                  }
    } else {
        sh 'ls'
    }
}
node{
    if (a == 0) {
         def status = sh (returnStdout:true, script:'cd /home/cadmus/GooBeeTeams_Git/goobeeteams/goobeeteams/goobeeteams | docker image build -t goobeeteams_api .')
                    if (status == 0) {
                        // Success!
                        sh 'docker container rm -f goobeeteams_frontend_1'
                                  }
    } else {
        sh 'ls'
    }
}
node('Docker Compose') {
  sh 'cd /home/cadmus/GooBeeTeams_Git/goobeeteams/goobeeteams && docker-compose up -d'
}
```

Comment: Try [How can I get multiple Jenkins builds to work from one local git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914664/how-can-i-get-multiple-jenkins-builds-to-work-from-one-local-git-repo).

Comment: once the code is checked out in your Jenkins workspace, you could probably do a git log to get the last modified file, get the parent directory using bash and set stage conditions to run only when the parent directory matches to be api or frontend. This way you'll have the deployment run only for the matching directory.